# Sending a credit card from UK to Colombia

Tags: uk, colombia, mail

I need to send a credit card from the UK to Bogota, Colombia.

I already tried sending the card (and, in the past, other letters) via regular Royal Mail international post, which I assume is received by some kind of standard postal service on the other end in Colombia (I don't know specifically which organisation this is), and nothing ever arrived (we're talking maybe 2 months ago here, those letters have definitely been lost in the system), and so I won't be trying this route again.

Instead, I'd really like to use a tracked mail service. Royal mail do offer a 'signed for' service to Colombia, but not a tracked service, and besides they clearly state that they always use foreign postal services after the mail has left the UK. So this is not an option.

I've had a look at several services including DHL, FedEx and UPS but they all seem to be geared more towards business mail, or sending large packages, and besides you seem to need an account with them to even get started - I don't know if this is a 'provide an email' style account or a 'sign up for a year at this monthly rate' style account.

What I want really is a Royal Mail style service, where you'd simply take a letter with the card in it to an office, pay there or use a prepaid ticket, get a tracking code, and that's it.

Can anyone recommend any services they've used for sending tracked personal letters, or suggest another solution? The cost isn't really a factor, within reason of course, as my bank has promised to refund the postage (long story short, their policies preclude them from sending cards out to Colombia, even with my authorisation, so I'm having to send it myself and get a refund as a workaround!)

Comment: Services like UPS should be perfectly usable for something like this.  Walk into a UPS office with your envelope and a credit card, and they'll send it - you don't have to be a business or register an account.  They aren't limited to large packages either - much of their business is A4-size envelopes sent around the world fast.  (Note, however, that the costs may be on the high side.)

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks, I've eventually found that DHL run their service from many high street stores, no accounts/pickup location necessary, seems like the easiest option.

Comment: Or a [Mail Boxes Etc](http://www.mbe.co.uk/) store. It might not be _cheap_ but you can be reasonably sure that it will arrive.

Comment: This is about international postage/couriers, not travel.

Comment: Having credit cards cancelled/lost/stolen is a pretty common problem for travellers in my experience. And for a country like Colombia, it's painful to post a new one out, hence courier services being required. With that said, would you mind explaining a bit further why you don't think this is on topic?